# Compiling SDWebImage demo: libwebp/src/utils/random.c not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, sdwebimage

On MacOS Mavericks I'm trying to compile [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) demo.

I have checked out the lastest release with

```
git clone https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git
```

and opened SDWebImage Demo.xcodeproj in Xcode 5.0.2.

Building the project however fails with (here [full-sized screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vNlQ.png)):

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'SDWebImage/Vendors/libwebp/src/utils/random.c'
clang: error: no input files
```

[image]

Where do I get this random.c please?

Or maybe it's possible to configure SDWebImage without webP support and then I won't need it?

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed that libwebp is a "git submodule" of the "SDWebImage" project - because when I was checking out again with SourceTree I have seen:

```
Submodule 'SDWebImage' (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git) registered for path 'SDWebImage'
Cloning into 'SDWebImage'...
Submodule path 'SDWebImage': checked out '42f97369726f1ee282b40b63616e339adfcb2c8a'
Submodule 'Vendors/libwebp' (http://git.chromium.org/webm/libwebp.git) registered for path 'Vendors/libwebp'
Cloning into 'Vendors/libwebp'...
Submodule path 'Vendors/libwebp': checked out '68e7901da53cbda6ec93ddf93e039346d3c6a531'
Completed successfully
```

Unfortunately, I don't know git that well yet and have to read on it - why wasn't this submodule downloaded when I cloned "SDWebImage"...

Comment: use --recursive method.
"git clone --recursive https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libwebp/+/refs/heads/master/src/utils

I have downloaded it and my build is ok:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

this works for me :

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git
```

Comment: This worked for me. Downloading the ZIP from GitHub.com it wouldn't compile, this fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation recently...

I needed to add the `SDWebImage` from github **as a Submodule** but when I tried to compile the project fails because there isn't files in *'Vendors'* folder and I solved my problem like that:

**I add the SDWebImage project as a sumbodule:**

- Go to the repo directory
- Type: `git submodule add git@github.com:<username>/example.git path/to/submodule`
- Type `git status` and notice how the supplied path was created and added to the changes to be commited. In addition a new file called `.gitmodules` was created, which contains the details we supplied about the new submodule.
- Commmit changes

Now, to solve my issue i did the following to **update each submodule that even has submodules**:

- Type: `git submodule update --init --recursive` from the repo directory
- Commit changes
- Push to remote